# Start/Stop twitter stream in background

Tags: php, twitter, stream, daemon

I'm discarding the old question for a better formulated question.
I'm using the twitter stream api via php like the script below.
When I run it via the command line. The script keeps running and when I hit ctrl+c the script stops.
Thats great and all, but i'd like to run it in the background. When a user creates a new search, the script below gets activated and stays running till a signal is given to sop. Just like the cli version, but in the background.

How do I achieve this?

Ok, here's a piece of code:

```
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => 'track=ipad'
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$stream  = fopen('http://test@stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json','r', false, $context);

while (!feof($stream)) {
    if (!($line = stream_get_line($stream, 200000, "\n"))) {
        continue;
    }

    $tweet = json_decode($line);
    // mysql query
}
```

I'm running it

Comment: I think at least **some** part of your relevant code might help!

Comment: I just updated the question ;)

Comment: Just want to let you know you leaked your twitter username and password in the code you posted. Better change it real quick before someone hijacks it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be solved by running the php script as a daemon from commandline, there are alot of things to conisder tho.

- what when the system reboots?
- what when an error occurs?
- what about memory management?
- what about monitoring?

A good start is Jeroen Keppens' presentation [PHP in the dark](http://www.amazium.com/blog/php-in-the-dark) he did on multiple php conference.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into `ajax` or other web-browser methods like comet or websockets to achieve what you want.

**update**
So if you want it to run on the server side you should use [php's exec function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) something like:

```
exec("php-cli runForever.php");
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the browser. It will be run on the server side in de background. When the user quits the browser, it still has to be going. Maybe for months, maybe for years.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But that way I cannot control the start and stop of the script. Any idea's on that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing with [this tutorial](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/). It uses the [System_Daemon](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon) pear package and provides **start/stop** functions.